# Trying to make a resistance wire heater to fool an air conditioner's thermostat.

Tags: resistance

I am trying to put together a fermentation chamber using a window air conditioner and a Johnson Controls A14 Temperature controller. The on-board thermostat of the AC unit will not let it run as low of a temperature as I need. I was wondering if it was possible to make a resistance wire heater to tape or shrink tube to the AC temperature sensor to fool it into thinking it is warmer than it actually is allowing the Johnson Controls temperature controller to control it instead? I was thinking of using a low voltage wall wart or something of that nature for the power source. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance

Comment: A classical example of XY problem. You want to do X, and somehow decided that Y is the right way to do it. Now you ask how to do Y, never mind how inefficient or dangerous it is. Well, at least you have mentioned X.

Comment: This is fairly commonly already done in old mechanical wall thermostats to provide a kind of proportional cycling, but I agree with the rest that it isn't a great way to go in your situation.

Comment: Yes, as bizarre as it sounds, I have a coworker whose refrigerator had a design problem and this was the manufacturer's solution instead of doing any kind of controller replacement they just had a service tech install something to warm up the outside temperature reading.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it should be possible.  No, it doesn't sound like a good idea.

Regular residential air conditioners are designed with some assumptions, including a lower limit on the temperature to cool too.  The unit might work very inefficiently, or not at all, at a temperature much below what it is intended for.  Icing will also quite likely be a problem, unless maybe you are in a very dry environment.

It sounds like you really want a refridgeration unit, not a air conditioner.

Comment: you do realize that we both just jinx'd each other & posted near identical answers @ the same time. ... No offence, but I thought we were about the last 2 people on this site for likelihood of doing that lol. +1

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB and now I have to up yours too since I already did this one.. LOL. Not sure either would freeze though, window bangers don't have a great TD value. Still not a good idea though

Comment: @Trevor After my time in the desert, one thing I've learned is to **never** bet *against* an ac unit freezing a coil...I've even seen an outdoor air handler AC unit freeze SOLID in 130*F heat with <20% RH! (And no, I did **not* take anyone's word for it on that...had to see the frozen coil with my own eyes before I believed it)

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB I believe it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you **could** use a heating element to fool the AC's thermostat into believing the room is 200 degrees F, then control it using your external thermostat.
2. No, you **should not** attempt to use a window-AC unit to cool below the lowest setting its internal thermostat is set for. A full explanation would belong in a different site, but suffice it to say that the best thing that would happen is you'd have a highly inefficient AC unit, up until you froze your coil & it became completely useless (lower temperature operation requires different refrigerant/pressure and a different design of the cooling coil).

Comment: Yes, the answers were within two minutes of each other, and quite close in content.  The question has meanwhile been closed, but have a +1 anyway.

Comment: Why did you VTC a question you have yourself answered? If you believe a question deserves to be answered, please don't close it, so others can contribute. If not, don't answer it yourself.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The closing criterion was valid, so I voted to close. However, rather than go back-and-forth in comments with OP about why the question needed changing, I decided to also post an answer that would "answer all their questions" & "help the OP out," but still let the question be relegated to the crypt, where it belongs. (the alternative(s) would have been less helpful to OP, and likely more destructive to the intent of this site)

Comment: Well, by answering this question you guys made it stick to the site forever, and two upvoted answers guarantee that it will be ranked high in search results. How is that not destructive?

Comment: With it high in search results, anyone wanting to ask a similar question might find their answer & not re-post...however, continued commenting on the question, or answers, is keeping it "fresh", and thus ranked highly on the main page (what I was trying to avoid)...not to mention that an upvoted answer takes it off the unanswered questions list instantly.